# Speed up zgrep on a multi-core computer

Tags: grep, gzip, multithreading

I'm running `zgrep` on a computer with 16 CPUs, but it only takes one CPU to run the task.

Can I speed it up, perhaps utilize all 16 cores?

P.S The IO is just fine, I could just copy the gzipped file into memory disk

Comment: use `pigz` instead, if you replace `gzip` with `pigz` `zgrep` should automatically use `pigz`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do as @UlrichDangel suggested in the comments and replace the executable `gzip` with `pigz`. If you want something a little less invasive you can also create functions for `gzip` and `gunzip` and add them to your `$HOME/.bashrc` file.

```
gzip() {
 pigz "$@"
}
export -f gzip

gunzip() {
 unpigz "$@"
}
export -f gunzip
```

Now when you run `zgrep` or `zcat` it will use `pigz` instead.

#### References

- [Replace bzip2 and gzip with pbzip2 and pigz system wide?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=106392)

Comment: Note that only `bash` scripts (like `zgrep` and `zcat` are on some systems) will benefit from that. And that only works if you're using `bash` as your interactive shell. (in other shells, you can do `export gzip='() { pigz "$@"; }'`...

Answer (score 1):

Or symlink /usr/local/bin/{gzip,gunzip} to respective binaries since that is likely to be in PATH before /usr/bin

> $ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pigz /usr/local/bin/gzip
>
> $ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/unpigz /usr/local/bin/gunzip
>
> $ which gzip
>
> /usr/local/bin/gzip
>
> $ gzip --help
>
> Usage: pigz [options] [files ...]